# loading otf font fails due to 'invalid version tag'

Tags: browser, fonts, polymer, webfonts

I have an element which requires a custom font ([this one, specifically](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Hattori-Hanzo)) and a Polymer code base. I import it in a separate `style` block as follows:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Hattori";
        src: url("../fonts/Hattori-Hanzo.otf");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
</style>
```

Then in Polymer's `dom-module` block I apply this font to a d3 item as follows:

```
var legend = main.append("g")
                    .attr("font-family", "Hattori")
```

However, in Chrome devtools I get:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/src/fonts/Hattori-Hanzo.otf
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

I checked, and the right font file is in the exact location specified by that url. I have another font in that exact folder being imported just fine by another component, in the same method, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with polymer: the OTS warning is the *browser* telling you that you're using an invalid font based on its font sanitizer analysis. Step 1: don't use `otf`, use `woff` (because that's the format for webfonts, which lets the browser ignore some things that *must* be enforced for universal system fonts with `tff` and `otf` extensions). And then if that doesn't work, time to check if the font is malformed with a real font utility like TTX.

Comment: I tried the `.woff` file but it's still complaining about the version tag. Not sure why; it's a perfectly legit font from the link I posted.

Comment: did you remember to tell the browser which format the font is using `src: url(...) format("woff")`? I downloaded the .otf and and used `src: url(Hattori_Hanzo.otf) format("opentype");` and that works fine, same for the woff version. I do get errors if I don't tell the browser what format it is, though.

Comment: `src: url("../fonts/Hattori-Hanzo.woff") format("woff");` still fails. Even if I try something I know should work, like a google font (doing `url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sarala")`, it still fails with the exact same message.

Comment: Can you create a separate pure html file with just that style loader for your font, and a single line `<p style="font-family: Hattori">test</p><p>test</p>` as content, to see if that works? (I assume you're not loading things from `file:///` here of course)